# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an - Optional Value

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have the following implementation; however, I am getting the following error.

> Thread 5: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

```
struct StoreProducts: Decodable {
  let totalProducts: Int?
  let pageNumber: Int?
}

var products: StoreProducts!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchProducts(completion: { success in
        print(self.products as Any)
        self.products = products
        self.productTableView.reloadData()
    })
}

func fetchProducts(completion: @escaping ((Any) -> Void)) {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://mobile-server.com/products/1/20"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return  }

    // Note: Swift 4 JSONCoder()
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            // getting error here
            self.products = try JSONDecoder().decode(StoreProducts.self, from: data)
            //check response status 200 OK
            if pageProducts.statusCode != 200
            {
                print("Connection issue, please try again later")
            }
            else{
                completion(self.products as Any)
            }
        }
        //check error
        catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: which line is your error?

Comment: Why do you have your products as a global variable instead of passing them as part of the completion handler?

Comment: @AndyIbanez, I am newbee to swift. I would like to learn what is the right way of doing it.

Comment: So I see many problems with your code, but the actual cause for the nil unwrapping is not clear yet. Try to post an MCVE that people can build and run to help you better.

Comment: It would be great, if you just describe the issues that you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and not sure where you declare the pageProducts but you need to check the response variable instead and cast it to HTTPURLReponse if you want to check the statusCode of the HTTP call.

```
fetchProducts(completion: { success in
  if let products = success as? StoreProducts
  {
     print(products.totalProducts!)
     print(products.pageNumber!)
   }
})


func fetchProducts(completion: @escaping ((AnyObject) -> Void)) {
    let jsonUrlString = "https://mobile-tha-server.appspot.com/walmartproducts/1/20"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return  }

    // Note: Swift 4 JSONCoder()
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)
    { (data, response, err) in
      guard let data = data else { return }
      do {
        // getting error here
        self.products = try JSONDecoder().decode(StoreProducts.self, from: data)
        //check response status 200 OK
        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
          print("Connection issue, please try again later")
        }
        else{
          completion(self.products as AnyObject)
        }
      }
        //check error
      catch let jsonErr {
        print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
      }
      }.resume()
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: do you have a valid URL that we can test? or can you post your other code?

Comment: let jsonUrlString = "https://mobile-tha-server.appspot.com/walmartproducts/1/20"

Comment: I edited my answer. I got a response of 224 products and 1 as pageNumber

Comment: please copy and paste my code to your environment and see if it works. It is working on my side.

Comment: Could you please include also URLSession part into your code?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: When I reloadTableView after data is retrived, then I am getting the following error .This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Comment: you need to enclosed your UI calls inside the main queue:

DispatchQueue.main.async
      {
        // ui function calls
      }